# Selenium Webdriver drag and drop not working for google.com

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Can not drag the image of **GOOGLE** logo to **Search field** from **www.google.com**. Tried with Acion Class, even JavascriptExecutor.

```
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

//      Element which needs to drag [Google Logo].          
        WebElement from=driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo"));    

//      Element on which need to drop [Google Search-bar].      
        WebElement to=driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

//      Using Action class for drag and drop.       
        Actions act=new Actions(driver);                    

//      Dragged and dropped.        
        act.dragAndDrop(from, to).build().perform();    

/*      JavascriptExecutor _js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        _js.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).simulate('drag-n-drop', 
        {dragTarget:arguments[1],interpolation: 
        {stepWidth:100,stepDelay:50}});", from, to);             
*/
```

I want to drag & hold the Google Image, then want Drop image to the search box, but nothing happened.
Manually if I drag and drop, I found image link like *https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png* in input serach box.

Even the below code works perfectly but not works for google.com!

```
public class DragAndDrop {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/droppable/default.html");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        Actions act=new Actions(driver);
        WebElement drag = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='draggable']"));
        WebElement drop = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='droppable']"));
        act.dragAndDrop(drag, drop).build().perform();
    }
```

Comment: 1. None of Browsers currently produce the HTML5 native drag and drop events. 2. So to write code that uses the HTML5 native drag and drop events (and is testable with selenium) you're going to need to use some JS that translates from mouse_down, mouse_move, mouse_up to the HTML5 native drag and drop events. 3. This is why it works on some sites (written to also work with pre HTML5 native drag and drop browsers) and not on others (only using HTML5 native drag and drop events). So in this case, how can I translate mouse event through JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try with ROBOT Class, It will helpful.

public class DragAndDrop 
    {
        static WebDriver driver;
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\workspace\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();       

            driver.get("http://google.com");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            WebElement dragFrom = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='abc']"));
            WebElement dragTo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='xyz']"));
            dragAndDropElement(dragFrom, dragTo);
        }
        public static void dragAndDropElement(WebElement dragFrom, WebElement dragTo) throws Exception 
        {
            // Setup robot
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.setAutoDelay(500);
            // Get size of elements
            Dimension fromSize = dragFrom.getSize();
            Dimension toSize = dragTo.getSize();
            Point toLocation = dragTo.getLocation();
            Point fromLocation = dragFrom.getLocation();
            //Make Mouse coordinate centre of element
            toLocation.x += toSize.width/2;
            toLocation.y += toSize.height/2 + 50 ;
            fromLocation.x += fromSize.width/2;
            fromLocation.y += fromSize.height/2 + 50;

            //Move mouse to drag from location
            robot.mouseMove(fromLocation.x, fromLocation.y);
            //Click and drag
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

            //Drag events require more than one movement to register
            //Just appearing at destination doesn't work so move halfway first
            robot.mouseMove(((toLocation.x - fromLocation.x) / 2) + fromLocation.x , ((toLocation.y - fromLocation.y) / 2) + fromLocation.y);

            //Move to final position
            robot.mouseMove(toLocation.x, toLocation.y);
            //Drop
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Though needs to add some values to adjust for both chrome and mozilla.  robot.mouseMove(toLocation.x, toLocation.y+40);